# Swift Constraints Don't Apply to All Sizes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, autolayout, size-classes

I'm trying to do something kinda of basic, but the Xcode has changed its constraint mechanism for size classes, apparently.
And so I want to know how to make this constraint actually apply for all size classes.

[iPhone 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm8dj.png)

[iPhone SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiR7R.png)

Comment: Don't use verify traits while applying the constraints and it will apply the constraints for all the size classes...

Comment: search for 'Auto Layout' related tutorials .

Comment: I wasn't using them the vary for Traits anyway @NishantBhindi

Answer (score 2):

Please check out these images with constraints and set your lay out accordingly.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it's what I have, it is really strange, I've never had something like this

Comment: but how did you change the size class to AnyAny

Answer (score 1):

It appears I just used a bad previously programmed view controller, I have created a new one, added the subviews and constrains, and everything works fine now.